# How to encode the single quote/apostrophe in JSON.NET

Tags: asp.net, json.net, json

How to encode the `'` to `\u0027` with JSON.NET?

So that the json string would look something like this:

```
{"Id":8,"CompanyName":"Jane\u0027s bakery"}
```

Comment: Why do you need to encode apostrophes in this way? `{"Id":8,"CompanyName":"Jane's bakery"}` is valid JSON.

Comment: JjQuery's parseJSON is failing with an exception because of the apostrophe..

Comment: I see. How does your front-end code get hold of the JSON?

Comment: for example
`declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{"qwe":"asd'qwe","zxc":"asd\"asd"}]';`
this will throw an error in sql. so, here should be used single quote escaping

Comment: Note: At least as of now (jQuery 3.6.3)  unescaped single quotes are no problem for `$.parseJSON`.

Answer (score 22):

Sample Call

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object,
   Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
   new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
   { StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml })
```

Comment: is it possible to encode with single quote? like this  `{'Id':8,'CompanyName':'Jane\u0027s bakery'}`?

Answer (score 7):

Json.NET 4.5 Release 11 added an option to control string escaping. One of the options is to escape all HTML characters which includes single quotes.

[JsonWriter.StringEscapeHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_StringEscapeHandling.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I assumed I had the same requirement, but @nick_w's comment made me realise I didn't need to escape the single quotes at all.

If you are generating json as a string in server side code, then outputting it into the client side javascript, so it can be converted to javascript objects, then escaping is not required.

(Code shown using asp style syntax)

Using extra steps requiring escaping single quotes...

```
var myData = JSON.parse('<%=myServerGeneratedStringWithSingleQuotesEscaped %>');
```

Using the JSON as it is...

```
var myData = <%=myServerGeneratedString %>;
```

Javascript will interpret an unquoted string such as

> [{"name":"Bill"}, {"name":"Ted"}]

as javascript objects.

As it's so easy to get mixed up when dealing with server side and client side strings, this reminder may be useful to someone. It may or may not apply to the OP - I'm sure there are many cases where single quotes genuinely need escaping.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But if `myServerGeneratedString` is empty and you drop the single quotas, there will be a JavaScript syntax error you cannot handle. If you keep the single quotas and `myServerGeneratedString` is empty, there will be no more damage than an empty string, which you can check. That's why I keep them even it is somehow ugly.

Answer (score -1):

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object,
   Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
   new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
   { StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml })`

is what I use when objects may contain an apostrophe, such as user names.

Comment: I downvoted because it is a exact copy of the answer from @Rizwan Ahmed. And it is badly formated also.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on your downvote. This is very rare and pleasing to see. Too many folks don't—I call them 'drive-by downvotes.' They're absolutely unproductive. | @AntoineThiry