# Tell Json.Net to write a single-quote rather than a double quote when serializing objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

When calling `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)` I'm getting keys and values enclosed in double quotes like this:

`{"key" : "value"}`

I would like them to be enclosed in single-quotes like this:

`{'key' : 'value'}`

Is it possible to do using Json.Net?

Comment: This seems to be a question already asked.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541998/how-to-encode-the-single-quote-apostrophe-in-json-net .  Refer to that question to see if it helps you out.

Comment: not really a pretty thing, but it works: `json.Replace("\"", "\'");`

Comment: I think that you can achieve your goal using a solution similar to the one used on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9280598/982431). The solution will pass from create a custom `JsonConverter` class that writes raw values and surround it with single quotes.

Comment: In 2018, you should avoid this -- JSON specifies that you should be using double quotes, and many parsing libraries will fail with single quotes now (because strictly speaking, it's not well formatted JSON anymore).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  If you use a `JsonTextWriter` explicitly instead of using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`, you can set the `QuoteChar` to a single quote.

```
var obj = new { key = "value" };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.QuoteChar = '\'';

    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
    ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{'key':'value'}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LGRl1k

Keep in mind that using single quotes around keys and values in JSON is considered non-standard (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)), and may cause problems for parsers that adhere strictly to the standard.

Comment: It's too troublesome.

Comment: It would be nice if they would add a setting to the JSON serializer settings where you could specify to use single quotes or double quotes. This code is a bit long but honestly the only thing I found that worked.