# Passing JSON Object as a claim of JWT Token in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Is it possible to pass a JSON object as a claim of JWT Token or list of objects (like shown on below example)?

```
{
  "nickname": [
    {
      "external_nickname": "tomas",
      "internal_nickname": "t_omas"
    }, 
    {
      "external_nickname": "malex",
      "internal_nickname": "alexander014"
    } 
  ]
}
```

So far I can only pass one nickname in token

```
"nickname" : "tomas"
```

Or I can pass an array

```
"nickname" : ["nickname1","nickname2"]
```

But none of these satisfies me.

EDIT:

Using Avin Kavish approach I got extra slashes in JSON Object. I don't want them. How to get rid of them?

```
 "nickname": "[{\"external_nickname\":\"tomas\",\"internal_nickname\":\"t_omas\"}]"
```

Comment: Are those in the client?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Comment: In javascript, `JSON.Parse(value)`. In c# `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value)` where T is your type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325107/tell-json-net-to-write-a-single-quote-rather-than-a-double-quote-when-serializi   Youc an write a method than uses the JSON.Net JsonTextWriter.QuoteChar

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as deserialising will remove the backslashes.

Answer (score 6):

For those using asp.net core, this is really simple. The claim object has an additional parameter.

```
new Claim("json", "{\"sample\":{\"sample\":\"value\"}}", JsonClaimValueTypes.Json)
```

The JsonClaimValueTypes is part of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Whew, StackOverflow to the rescue again! THANKYOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the underlying structures you will find that the `JWTPayload` class inherits from `Dictionary<string,object>`. Once we know that, the rest is easy:

```
// Build the claims list somehow, may contain nested objects
// NOTE: any nested data must be JSON-serializable!
Dictionary<string,object> claims = BuildMeThatClaimsList();

// Add all claims manually because the CTORs only accept string values
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, Array.Empty<Claim>(), notBefore, expires, signingCreds);
foreach (var pair in claims)
  token.Payload.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
return token;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, serialize it first.

```cs
var claim = new Claim("nickname", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nicknames));
```

In order to use the nicknames, you need to deserialize from a string back to a plain old object.

In javascript,

```
const nicknames = JSON.Parse(value)
```

In C#,

```cs
var nicknames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value) // <-- where T is your type
```

Comment: There are slashes present i JWT Token using your approach. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think the slashes are great for escaping the double quotes in the serialized object, can't you remove them when you use the claims eg. from your client?

Answer (score 2):

I use JWT NuGet package.

```
Install-Package JWT
```

the code:

```
        var payload = new
        {
            nickname = new[]
            {
                new {external_nickname = "tomas", internal_nickname = "t_omas"},
                new {external_nickname = "malex", internal_nickname = "alexander014"}
            }
        };
        
        var encoder = new JwtEncoder(new HMACSHA256Algorithm(), new JsonNetSerializer(), new JwtBase64UrlEncoder());
        var token = encoder.Encode(payload, "your_secret");
```